# changing xcode 4 file associations

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xcode4

Where do I go in xcode 4 to change the default of my file being open by preview to text editor?

i.e. I have a model.dae which keeps opening in preview but i want to open it with text edit.

I've already changed it in finder to open with text edit.
I can right click and use open as but i want to change the default

thanks

Answer (score 0):

right click on that and select the getInfo.There you will find the openwith.There you can select the option as textEdit.

Comment: apparently im not seeing a get info when right click in xcode 4. i did see it in xcode 3 however